# Merge data based on column match

Tags: sed, awk

I have a record as follows (Input) .There are `8` fields and each fields are separated by `tab space`.From the above records I need to generate a new file as follows based on `1,2,4,5` column match.

Input file:

```
-10 68120047    .   X   Y   .   Pass    A=0.0257732
-10 68120047    .   X   Y   .   Pass    B=0.0263158
-10 68120047    .   X   Y   .   Pass    C=0.0280899
```

output

```
-10 68120047    .   X   Y   .   Pass    A=0.0257732;B=0.0263158;C=0.0280899
```

Comment: and..... what have you tried???

Comment: from your description (`8 fields sep by tab...based on 1,2,4,5 column ...)`, the `Line 1,2,3:` should not in input file. I removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example `1,2,4,5` don't match!. you have `y` and `Y`

try this one-liner with `$1 and $2` as key. you could add to `$1 $2 $4 $5` too.

```
awk '{r=$NF;k=$1$2;a[k]=a[k]?a[k]";"r:$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

with your content in file:

```
kent$  awk '{r=$NF;k=$1$2;a[k]=a[k]?a[k]";"r:$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file 
-10  68120047    .   X   Y   .   Pass    A=0.0257732;B=0.0263158;C=0.0280899
```

Comment: Working but B,C fields are coming in new line

Comment: @sudo_O yes it does. the `Line x:` should not be in input. At the beginning I wrote more complicated line than this. however after I read his question twice, I found it. see my comment under the question.

Comment: @AbhinRaj I cannot see it happen here. or you have a different input file?

Comment: @AbhinRaj as I said, your example has `y` and `Y` in 5th col. they are not same, if you just add `$4$5` to my `k` variable. you got B,C in a new line, with the small `y`.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable assumption @AbhinRaj please confirm this.

Comment: @Kent Tried this awk '{l=$0;r=$NF;k=$1$2$4$5;a[k]=a[k]?a[k]";"r:l}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file

But B,C fields are writing in new line I should add 4th and 5th column match it is exactly Y and not y

Comment: @AbhinRaj I have to repeat it again and again~  it comes in new line, because in your intput `y` `Y` are different! change them into same `y` or `Y` you wrote in your question match `1,2,4,5` but your input doesn't. are we clear?

Comment: @Kent it is Y not y typing mistake